# Appending values in rows into new columns?

Tags: python

I have this data in a CSV:

```
first, middle, last, id, fte
Alexander,Frank,Johnson,460700,1 
Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,.5 
Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,.25 
Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,.25 
Steve,Robert,Brown,460001,1
```

I need to find the rows of people with the same ID numbers, and then combine the FTEs of those rows into the same line.  I'll also need to add 0s for the rows that don't have duplicates.  For example (using data above):

```
first, middle, last, id, fte1, fte2, fte3, fte4
Alexander,Frank,Johnson,460700,1,0,0,0
Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,.5,.25,.25,0
Steve,Robert,Brown,460001,1,0,0,0
```

Basically, we're looking at the jobs people hold.  Some people work one 40-hour per week job (1.0 FTE), some work two 20-hour per week jobs (.5 and .5 FTEs), some might work 4 10-hour per week jobs (.25, .25, .25, and .25 FTEs), and some may have other combinations.  We only get one row of data per employee, so we need the FTEs on the same row.

This is what we have so far. Right now, our current code only works if they have two FTEs.  If they have three or four, it just overwrites them with the last two (so if they have 3, it gives us 2 and 3.  If they have 4, it gives us 3 and 4).

```
f = open('data.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
dataset = []
for row in csv_f:
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary["first"] = row[2]
    dictionary["middle"] = row[3]
    dictionary["last"] = row[4]
    dictionary["id"] = row[10]
    dictionary["fte"] = row[12]
    dataset.append(dictionary)

def is_match(dict1, dict2):
    return (dict1["id"] == dict2["id"])

def find_match(dictionary, dict_list):
    for index in range(0, len(dict_list)):
        if is_match(dictionary, dict_list[index]):
            return index
    return -1

def process_data(dataset):
    result = []
    for index in range(1, len(dataset)):
        data_dict = dataset[index]
        match_index = find_match(data_dict, result)
        id = str(data_dict["id"])
        if match_index == -1:
            result.append(data_dict)
        else:
            (result[match_index])["fte2"] = data_dict["fte"]
    return result

f.close()

for row in process_data(dataset):
    print(row)
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use the pandas library to make it simple. You can use group by along with aggregation. The below is an example following the aggregation example provided here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

grouped = df.groupby('id')
print grouped['fte'].agg(np.sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried this, and it worked to group all of the scores together, but then it summed them instead of printing the individual values.  So, I'm getting:

    `Alexander,Frank,Johnson,460700,1
    Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,1
    Steve,Robert,Brown,460001,1`

Instead of:

    `Alexander,Frank,Johnson,460700,1
    Ashley,Jane,Smith,470000,.5, .25, .25
    Steve,Robert,Brown,460001,.5,.5`